# How to add a number to dict value every time i call it?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to put a dictionary which contains user information into a new json file and i want it to give every user a number when i call a function 'new_user'. How can i do it?

```
from get_stars import rate_service
user_info = {
    'user_number': int(),
    'user_info': {
        'username': 'username',
        'user_location': 'user_location',
        'used_application': 'used_application',
        'stars': int()
    }
}

def get_user_info():
    new_user = user_info.copy()
    new_user['user_info']['username'] = input(f"\nEnter your name: ")
    new_user['user_info']['stars'] = rate_service()
    return new_user
```

```
from userinfo import get_user_info
import json

def new_user():
    user = get_user_info()
    filename = f"user.json"
    with open(filename, 'w'):
        json.dump(filename, user)
```

For example i call that func and in my json file there is dict with user number 1, but when i call it next time this number increases by 1

Comment: Why not simply increment `user_info['user_number'] += 1` before you copy `user_info` to `new_user`? Of course, this leaves the issue of persistence across multiple runs of your program, but you could solve that by saving the current `user_info` to a separate json file and then reading from the file the next time you load the program.

Comment: Good question, don't even know why i didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid reading the file before assigning the number I would use a Guuid, that is basically a random number so big that is at all effects guaranteed not to collide with others.

If you want to assign a integer then you have two choices:

1. reading the files taking the max value and assign before setting
   the user info
2. having another file with the "metadata" of the user
   count which you will also read.

Normally this kind of operations are made using a database that will take care out of them.

You can also use a indexed dataframe a numerated dictionary or even a list of user as a middle data-structure that will help you if you go for the option 1.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't really understand the first point. I could user uuid, but i want user_id to be more readble, so it could be easy to count etc. If you don't mind i can give you little bit more details on messenger or instagram.

Comment: Just read the files, and extracting the maximun value or the length of the list, to know what will be the next number, but is not ideal as you will need to load an increasing amount of data to do this. But you can also try to load only the last entry.

Comment: Well, now i got your point, but i have no idea how to load only the last entry without reading all file and exctracting the length of dictionary :D

Comment: For a small amount of data is ok to load it all, just not scalable for a big project.

Comment: But you can save just this number elsewhere as "metadata" so you don't load everything, is also not the best practice, but for the best practice you should be using a proper database.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just a beginner so i don't know a thing about databases. I'll try both methods

Answer (score 0):

Assign a uuid: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

```
import uuid

new_user = {}

new_user['user_number'] = uuid.uuid1()

# output: {'user_number': UUID('d2586590-abb8-11ec-94de-acde48001122')}
print(new_user)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that exists